# How show view overlay another view and change view size

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, modalviewcontroller

**How to achieve below task?**

[image: Overlay view]

**Explanation:**

I want to show collection view over main view.  Collection view must shown on half screen and change size to full screen by gesture(drag or swipe).

Please help me. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think. I must use modalPresentationStyle and transitioningDelegate.

for half screen user UIView.animate with 
 CGRect(x: 0, y: containerView!.bounds.height / 2, width: containerView!.bounds.width, height: containerView!.bounds.height / 2)